# A long URL displayed as a word linked to the URL

Tags: javascript, php

**Hello guys,**

I want to add an exception for a single {$item.Key} which is a long URL, to be displayed as a text linked to the URL. So on the front end, when a user insert his own URL, to be displayed as a word linked to that URL.

Thank You for your help!

```
<div class="table-cell {if $group.Key == 'common'}col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 two-columns{/if} clearfix{if $small} small{/if}{if ($item.Type == 'checkbox' && $item.Opt1) || $item.Type == 'textarea'} wide-field{if $item.Type == 'textarea'} textarea{/if}{/if}" id="df_field_{$item.Key}">
{if $item.Type == 'image' && $small}{else}
    <div class="name" title="{$item.name}">{if !$small}<div><span>{$item.name}</span></div>{else}{if $item.name}{$item.name}{else}{$lang[$item.pName]}{/if}{/if}</div>
{/if}
<div class="value{if $item.Type == 'image'} image{/if}">
    {if $item.Type == 'checkbox' && is_array($item.Values)}
        <ul class="checkboxes row clearfix">
        {foreach from=$item.Values item='tile' name='checkboxF'}
                {if !empty($item.Condition)}
                    {assign var="tit_source" value=$tile.Key}
                {else}
                    {assign var="tit_source" value=$tile.ID}
                {/if}
                {if $item.Opt1 || $tit_source|in_array:$item.source}
                    <li title="{$lang[$tile.pName]}" class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-4 {if $tit_source|in_array:$item.source}active{/if}">
                        <img src="{$rlTplBase}img/blank.gif" alt="" />{$lang[$tile.pName]}
                    </li>
                {/if}
        {/foreach}
        </ul>
    {else}
        {$item.value}
    {/if}
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question? Where is the error?

Comment: Is not an error, I just want to add an exception, for a field, to display a hyperlinked text instead of the long URL

Comment: And... you want someone else to code it for you? The idea of Stackoverflow is to create your own code and if it doesn't work the way you expected, or doesn't work at all you ask help, share your code, tell what does happen, tell what should happen and so on. Either I misunderstand what you are asking (apologies if so) or you misunderstand the system.